# Lognormal distributed random variable excercise

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let Y be a random variable distributed Lognormally, Q1 be it's first quartile, Q3 it's third quartile and M be its median: prove that-
 M - Q1 < Q3 - M

I have managed to figure out that Q3 > M > Q1 already, but no success on from here. any clues ?

Comment: Can you show that Lognormal distribution is postively skewed? Because positive skewness implies $Q_3-M>M-Q_1$ in general.

Comment: I have done that. And I already read since posting this that positive skewing implies this but i still cant understand nor explain why...

Comment: That is the interpretation of [Bowley's measure of skewness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Quartile-based_measures).